# Possible reasons for failing to turn on ignition, strange vibration and sudden stop of engine?

Tags: engine, ford, ignition, vibration

My car is Ford Laser 1992 auto. Maybe it is too old. I have to turn the key a couple of time to start the engine. Recently I found it difficult to turn it on. As soon as it starts (and I switch to reverse), the engine would suddenly stop and I can't get it started for a while no matter how many times turning the key (sounds like power exhausted). I refilled the oil but it still won't help. I've got the car started this morning but I don't feel secured with the strange vibration (like coughing).

Can anyone tell me what can be the possible cause?

Comment: What kind of maintenance work has been done on it lately other than oil?

Comment: no maintenance work has been done except for changing a brake pad, but that's not relevant to the problem I think @justinm410

Comment: Does it run smoother after warming up?

Comment: Yes, but after a while engine will suddenly stop @justinm410

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem confirmed: distributor damaged. Possibly the 4 plugs worn down and back fired to the distributor so they may also need to be replaced. See if that makes sense.